# Dynamic column selection in Excel

Tags: dynamic, excel-formula, range

I have a table in excel with months as columns and couple of rows with data.  I would like to add a column on the end of the table that will populate with data from the table as the YTD sum of the month columns.  The YTD sum will be based on dynamic selection of the month selected from a list.  Have a look at the attached image to see what I mean please, in the example Aug-16 has been selected in column P and the YTD total is returned correctly for this period (this is what I want to happen, but not sure how to?:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPjzA.png)

The dynamic selector I can do fine (Data validation -> list) but I'm not sure how to populate the column with the correct data, that is YTD for the month selected in the dynamic column added.  Not sure if it can be done with MATCH, INDEX etc?  I tried, also VLOOKUP, but not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use this formula using the same parameters as your example image.

`=SUM(C3:OFFSET(C3,0,MATCH($P$2,$C$2:$N$2,0)-1))`